# Using WPF MediaElement with MKV video format - no audio

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, mediaelement

I'm attempting to play .mkv video files using the MediaElement control in WPF/VB.  The video works great, but I've yet to get audio from any of the .mkv files that I've tried. Typical audio codecs for my .mkv files are A52 Audio (aka AC3) or DTS.

All of the .mkv files play fine (with audio) in Windows Media Player (v 12.0).

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800" WindowState="Normal" Background="Black">

    <Grid>
        <MediaElement x:Name="meVideo" Width="800" Height="450" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Volume="1" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

VB:

```
Private Sub meVideo_Loaded(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles meVideo.Loaded
    meVideo.LoadedBehavior = MediaState.Manual
    meVideo.Source = New Uri("D://video.mkv", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)
    meVideo.Play()
End Sub
```

Is this a limitation of the MediaElement or am I missing some functionality here.  If it is a limitation, can you recommend an alternative control with simple implementation? (FLAC support would be a plus in an alternative control.)

Thanks!

Comment: If you play the .mkv in windows, perhaps with media player, do you get audio?

Comment: @Jodrell Yes, the video and audio both play correctly in Windows Media Player.  Also, I forgot to mention that if I test for HasAudio, it returns True.

Comment: I had to ask, I won't think about volume settings.

Comment: Yeah, I currently have volume set to 1.  If it matters, I have CoreAVC/Haali Media Splitter on my system.

Comment: Any other ideas out there? :)

Comment: Did you found a fix for this problem? Do you know if MediaElement can use an specific set of codecs? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need at least Windows Media Player 10 or above to be able to use MediaElement properly. Windows XP doens't include that.